# CSS conditionals for IE is not loaded when including  <ui:composition template>

Tags: css, jsf, load, conditional-statements

Have xhtml `templ.xhtml` layout.

Include it to other .xhtml like:

```
<ui:composition template="/template/templ.xhtml">
```

Define conditionals in templ.xhtml like:

```
<h:head>
 <h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if lt IE 8]&gt;&lt;h:outputStylesheet library=&quot;css&quot; name=&quot;styleie8.css&quot; /&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false" />
</h:head>
```

`styleie8.css` is not loaded,but when something changed and saved in `templ.xhtml` when Tomcat is running,that it loaded ok.

How to do,that JSF loads conditionals immediately when Tomcat started?

**Note:**
tried to use following alternatives:
**1.**

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
                <h:outputStylesheet name="styleie8.css" library="css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

**2.**

```
<o:conditionalComment if="lte IE 8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleie8.css" />
</o:conditionalComment>
```

**3.** `#{request.contextPath}/resources` instead of simple path.
 
The result is the same - I need **resave** .xhtml template in order to load conditionals css.

Comment: can you provide the HTML that gets generated with what you already tried?

Comment: `<!--[if lt IE 8]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleie8.css" /><![endif]-->`

Comment: Please note that it's the webbrowser who has to download the CSS file, not the webserver (nor JSF) who has to "include" the CSS file somehow. Please check if it isn't just the browser cache who caused this.

Comment: I tried already `CTRL-R` and `CTRL-F5`.Didn't help.The same issue is in `IE Tester` and in pure IE browsers.Conditionals is loaded after some changed and resaved in template xhtml only while `Tomcat running`.That is the main problem.

Comment: BalusC,perhaps I shoud try composite component

Comment: Can you try and clear the folder `<pathToYourTomcat>/work/Catalina/localhost/<yourContextPath>`?

Comment: @sergionni, just curios , have you tried `<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/styleie8.css" /><![endif]-->`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial code snippet is wrong. You can't print a `<h:outputStylesheet>` in a `<h:outputText escape="false">`. The `<h:outputStylesheet>` is a JSF component which is supposed to generate HTML, but in a `<h:outputText escape="false">` it would be printed literally as-is. If you open the page in browser and do rightclick, *View Source*, then you should have discovered this yourself. This is not right. The webbrowser understands only HTML which should be `<link rel="stylesheet">`.

Provided that you've placed the stylesheet in `/resources/css/styleie8.css`, then the following should work:

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if lte IE 8]&gt;&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/styleie8.css&quot; /&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false" />
```

As to the alternatives you tried, 1) would not work as it would be escaped. 2) should work assuming that the `href` points to the right URL. In the example as you've posted, it assumes the CSS file to be in the same folder as the view. However, if it is still located in `/resources/css/styleie8.css`, then you should have used:

```
<o:conditionalComment if="lte IE 8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/styleie8.css" />
</o:conditionalComment>
```

3) should work, assuming that you provided the right URL.

Comment: I notice one more time: it works ok ,when xhtml resaved,e.g. Tomcat started with `<o:conditionalComment if="lte IE 8">` ,UI is corrupted.Then I change something in xhtml and resave and it works OK.

Comment: If it doesn't work when you start Tomcat, but then works when you "touch" the file server-side, I'm very curious about the generated HTML and the requests that your browser does. Can you post these two HTML snippets and if possible a screenshot of Firebug (or IE alternative) showing what the browser tried to load?

Answer (score 1):

The following line will just output your string:

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if lt IE 8]&gt;&lt;h:outputStylesheet library=&quot;css&quot; name=&quot;styleie8.css&quot; /&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false" />
```

`h:outputStylesheet` is also just outputted and **not** handled as a component. Like this `h:outputStylesheet` **is** used as a component:

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if lt IE 8]&gt;" escape="false" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styleie8.css" />
<h:outputText value="&lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false" />
```

I think you where close with your second alternative. You probably ran into a 404 error because of a missing context path there.

Comment: Right, the `<h:outputText>` should print a `<link rel="stylesheet">`, not a `<h:outputStylesheet>`, but please note that using `<h:outputStylesheet>` this way won't work as it would be relocated. His question is after all confusing as alternative #2 should work outright.

Comment: the problem is reproduced. I've said,that its due to using template,conditionals css loaded in runtime only after some chnges performed

Comment: BalusC, I respect omnifaces minimalizm,but it doens' work in my case really) Some problem with including templates